# Binding form data to a list of objects with Java Play 2

Tags: java, data-binding, playframework-2.0

I have a table in a form that I want to bind each row to an object and then add that object to a list on the server side, but when I do form.bindFromRequest(), I get null values and I can't figure out the binding. The following is my HTML/form.

```
<tr>
    <td><input type="hidden" value="@domains(i).id" name="domains[@i].domainId" readonly></td>
    <td><input type="text" value="@domains(i).domain" name="domains[@i].domain"></td>
    <td><input type="text" class="no-default-datepicker" value="@domains(i).date.format("yyyy-MM-dd")" name="domains[@i].date" /></td>
    <td><input type="hidden" value="@domains(i).cycle" name="domains[@i].cycle">@domains(i).cycle</td>
    <td>@defining(if (domains(i).blacklist == true) "checked" else "") { checked =>
        <input name="domains[@i].blacklist" type="checkbox" @checked />}
        <input type="hidden" name="domains[@i].blacklist" value="false"></td>
    <td><input type="text" value="@domains(i).source" name="domains[@i].source"></td>
    @for( x <- domains(i).results.indices){
        <td><input type="text" value="@domains(i).harvestResults(x).results" name="domains[@i].results[@x].results"></td>
    }
</tr>
```

Edit: Server-side code, but it's wrong and doesn't work. I can't get the harvestResults subclass to bind when I get the form.

```
    public static Result update(){
    Form<EditClass> form = form(EditClass.class).bindFromRequest();
    EditClass ec = form.get(); //problem starts here, the harvestResults won't work. 

    return redirect("/search");
}
```

Data model:

```
public class Domain {

public static class HarvestInformation{
    @JsonProperty("_id")
    public String id;
    public String name;
    public String results;
}

@JsonProperty("_id")
public String id;
public String domain;
public Boolean bl;
public String source;
public Date date;
public Integer cycle;
public List<HarvestInformation> harvestResults;
```

}

Comment: Please share your `form` variable..

Comment: Please also post your form handling code

Comment: That's not existent atm because I can't get it to bind so I just scrapped it. I'll grab my code when I get a chance. I was more asking how would I structure the server-side code to deal with the nested classes.